# CPLEX max function over a range

Tags: optimization, routes, cplex

I have a non-linear constraint in the form of max_{k in V, j in F^o: o > d} {U_{jk} - U_{ik} > 0 for all i in F^d. The set V denotes a fleet of vehicles, while F^o represent customers of a certain type and F^i represents customers of a certain type. How do I implement a max function that will be able to compute this in CPLEX, maxl() and IloMAx() does not seem to work

Comment: It could just be me, but it's not very clear what you're asking here. Can you give an example of what one of these non-linear constraints looks like exactly? It might help if you show a snippet of your code instead.  You say that IloMax does not work.  What happens?  Is an exception thrown?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly your `max` function is to return the maximum value, among the positive values, of `U_jk - U_ik` for all `k in V` and `j in F^o` such that `o > d`. If that is correct all you need is a couple of loops, one on the `k` and another one on the `j`. For each `(k, j)` pair you need then to verify all the conditions:

1. Exceeding the higher value obtained; while also
2. Having a positive value for `U_jk - U_ik`.

I'll assume you will have the `o > d` condition checked outside the max function to simplify it. I propose you to do it as follows:

```
IloInt myMaxFunction(IloIntArray V, IloIntArray Fo, Ilo2IntArray U, IloInt i) {
    IloInt jMax;//    j index of the maximum value
    IloInt kMax;//    k index of the maximum value
    IloInt maxVal = -IloInfinity;//  maximum value
    IloInt Difference;

    for (IloInt k = 0; k < V.getSize(); k++) {
        for (IloInt j = 0; j < Fo.getSize(); j++) {
            Difference = U[F0[j]][V[k]] - U[i][V[k]];

            if ((Difference > 0) && (Difference > maxVal)) {
                jMax = j;
                kMax = k;
                maxVal = Difference;
            }
        }       
    }

return maxVal;
}
```

You will be entering the two linear arrays, the first containing the sets of vehicles, the second one containing the customers farther than a distance `d` to the depot *I assume*. The third parameter is a bidimensional set of integers you can define with: `typedef IloArray<IloIntArray> Ilo2IntArray`. Finally, you will also need the customer `i` as input.

For all `(k, j)` pair of elements such that `k` is a vehicle in `V` and `j` is a customer on the set `F^o` you will compute the difference `U_jk - U_ik`, verify simultaneously the aforementioned conditions. In such case, you will update the indexes and maximal value and continue.

Notice, that `maxVal` **must** be initialized to a value that will be improved the first time the conditions are verified. The best/higher value will be returned by the function.

One is glad to be of service...
Y